# probability that $A$ and $B$ answer the question differently given probabilities each is telling the truth if they act independently of each other

Tags: probability, solution-verification

I got homework at the University and I think I solved this, but I am not sure, that my solution is right. Can somebody check it? Thank you!

Suppose the person $A$ tells the truth with a probability of $0.75$ and the person $B$ with a probability of $0.8$. Both persons act independently of each other. Determine the probability that $A$ and $B$ answer a given question differently.

$\textbf{My solution:}$

Since they act independently we have $\mathbb{P}(A \cap B)=\mathbb{P}(A)\cdot \mathbb{P}(B).$ And I have to determine the probability of "A says true and B says lie" and "A says lie and B says true". Because we have the different answers only in this two cases. Lets say

$\mathbb{P}(A)=0.75$ "A says true"

$\mathbb{P}(A^c)=1-0.75=0.25$ "A says lie". The same for $B$. Then we have (A and B are independent)
$\mathbb{P}(A \cap B^C)+ \mathbb{P}(B \cap A^c)=\mathbb{P}(A) \cdot \mathbb{P}(B^c)+\mathbb{P}(B) \cdot \mathbb{P}(A^c)=0.75\cdot 0.20+0.8 \cdot 0.25=0.35$.

Is it correct?

Comment: Yep, you're correct

Comment: @marlite thank you!

Comment: As is often the case with these problems, the wording is unclear.  In particular, you are assuming that, if they both lie, then they both say the same thing though of course this need not be true.  Presumably you have in mind some binary situation...like a coin is tossed, both parties look at it, and can only say Heads or Tails.  In that case, of course, if both lie then they would say the same thing.  Worth making that explicit.